# xslt 2.0 variable element node set processing

Tags: xslt, tomcat

I am trying to transform xml into a new structure and then process the new structure within a transformation. My problem is getting the new structure to be usable as a node set. I am using Tomcat 6 with saxon9he in the webapp's lib. To test the usability of the new structure, I have created the following xsl's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:include href="nodeTest.xsl"/>
<xsl:variable name="theDoc"> 
  <doc>
    <source>from</source>
    <source>here</source>
    <target>to</target>
    <target>there</target>
  </doc>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="result1">
    <xsl:call-template name="createLinks">
    <xsl:with-param name="doc" select="$theDoc/doc/*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
input:
<xsl:value-of select="$theDoc/doc/*"/>
output:
<xsl:value-of select="$result1"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expect that the variable theDoc will contain a valid node set, and that the createLinks template will process it as a node set. Here is the creatlelInks template;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="makeLink"> 
  <xsl:param name="theSource" select="'source'"/>
  <xsl:param name="theTarget" select="'target'"/>
  <xsl:param name="theUsage" select="'usage'"/>
  <xsl:element name="link" >
  <xsl:element name="usage" ><xsl:value-of select="$theUsage"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="source" ><xsl:value-of select="$theSource"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="target" ><xsl:value-of select="$theTarget"/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="createLinks">
<xsl:param name="doc" select="*"/>
the input doc:
<xsl:value-of select="$doc"/>
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:element name="Links">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="makeLink" select=".">
      <xsl:with-param name="theUsage" select="'link from source to target'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="theSource" select="$doc/source/*"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="theTarget" select="$doc/target/*"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:element>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When executed, the results look like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
input:
from here to there
output:

the input doc:
fromheretotherelink from source to target
```

It is apparent that theDoc is not a node set. My understanding is that the xslt 2.0 standard would have theDoc as a node set, and not a result tree fragment. How can I change these simple xsls to process the contents of theDoc as a node set?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me how you come to your conclusion:

"It is apparent that theDoc is not a node set. My understanding is that the xslt 2.0 standard would have theDoc as a node set, and not a result tree fragment. How can I change these simple xsls to process the contents of theDoc as a node set?"

The first problem here is that you are using XSLT 1.0 data model terminology. In 2.0, there are no node sets, only sequences, and there is no such thing as a result tree fragment.

The value of $theDoc is a document node. This document node has a child element called doc, which in turn has four children called source, source, result, and result.

When you do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$doc"/>
```

it outputs the string value of this document node, which is the concatenation of the descendant text nodes, namely `fromheretothere`.

When you do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$result1"/>
```

you output the string value of $result1, which is itself a document node; this document node has a child called link, which has three children, called usage, source, and target; the usage element has text content 'link from source to target', and the source and target elements are both empty. The reason they are empty is that the expressions `$doc/source/*` and `$doc/target/*` select nothing; they select nothing because $doc has a child called doc; the source and target elements are its grandchildren.

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of issues in your XSLT which stop it from working as you expect. The first is where you use **xsl:value-of** to show the value of the variable. For example

```
<xsl:value-of select="$doc"/>
```

This will only show the text value of the node-set. You should be using **xsl:copy-of** here really, to return a copy of the nodes.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$doc" />
```

Try replacing all your occurrences of **xsl:value-of** with **xsl:copy-of** to see how you get on.

Secondly, there is an issue with your parameters when you call the 'makelink' template

```
<xsl:with-param name="theSource" select="$doc/source/*"/>
<xsl:with-param name="theTarget" select="$doc/target/*"/>
```

The * will match child elements of the **source** and **target** elements, but they have no child elements, only child text nodes (Elements are nodes, but not all nodes are elements!). You probably want to do this....

```
<xsl:with-param name="theSource" select="$doc/source"/>
<xsl:with-param name="theTarget" select="$doc/target"/>
```

In fact, even that will not work because of how you are calling your template

```
<xsl:call-template name="createLinks">
    <xsl:with-param name="doc" select="$theDoc/doc/*"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Calling it this way means **source** and **target** are the top-level elements. You probably want to do this instead...

```
 <xsl:call-template name="createLinks">
     <xsl:with-param name="doc" select="$theDoc/doc"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: the copy-of did show the results I expected - after modifying the  selection syntax as you pointed out... thanks